# Adjust Transparency on ArcGIS Image Layer

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to adjust the transparency of a PNG that I am overlaying on ArcGIS/ESRI API for Javascript.

I have tried to set an `opacity` option in the `var` but, am not having much luck.

```
map.on("load", function() {
// create and add the layer
var mil = new esri.layers.MapImageLayer({
});

// create an add the actual image
var mi = new esri.layers.MapImage({
  'extent': { 'xmin': -125.0, 'ymin': 22.0, 'xmax': -66.5, 'ymax': 52.0},
  'href': 'https://some.website/some.image.PNG',
  'opacity': 0.75
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `opacity: 0.6` to

```
map.on("load", function() {
// create and add the layer
var mil = new esri.layers.MapImageLayer({
  'opacity': 0.6,
});
```